# Can wires related to modems and internet emit harmful radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation

I am installing internet services at my house and need to run wires (Ethernet, modem, router related) along the lower part of the wall near some beds.  Can people sleeping in the beds be exposed to harmful radiation (cancer-causing) from these wires?

Edit: my concern lies primarily with all the different sorts of wires involved.  But I'd be curious about the router and modem too

Comment: To be clear: are you worried about the wires or about the devices (router, modem)?

Comment: All the wires involved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People have had internet wires in their houses for 20+ years, and while not all cables run close to beds, certainly some do so -  given the omnipresence of this kind of wires - if there were harmful effects, we’d know by now.  Never mind bedrooms think of offices, where people would also be exposed for  long periods.

So we can say with almost certainly that it’s highly unlikely that this kind of wiring has adverse health effects over periods in the 20+ year range.  Moreover, technology is improving, so we can also say that those who have been exposed in the early 2000s were probably more exposed than people nowadays so the exposure risk is likely decreasing in time on a per-device basis.  It could be that overall exposure has increased as the prevalence of the modems and routers has increased, but again: it’s not like there’s a detectable increase in cancer, at least not an increase attributable internet cables or gear.

This *isn’t* like cigarettes, for instance, where the adverse effects where known on animals, and where the prevalence of lung cancer was easily detectable as function of the age and as a function of nicotine consumption of individuals.

There is current no evidence to suggest that wifi radiation, or anything related to the wiring of internet gear, had adverse health effects.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Sotry to nitpick how about distance from the wires? Is there a certain distance where the risk becomes virtually zero?  If you are farther than say, one foot, does that significantly reduce the already low risk?

Comment: The only kind of conceivable potential hazard would come from something similar to “direct coupling”, which happens when you are within 2-3 centimetres away from an antenna.   Then it’s possible theoretically that the extreme proximity to a device may somehow induce non-linear effect in the ear or the brain: no effect has *ever* been recorded.   This is not my area of expertise,  but comsider https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2018/jul/21/mobile-phones-are-not-a-health-hazard?CMP=Share_iOSApp_Other which goes beyond a headline of the questionable link between cell phone and cancer.

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

No more than your power wires to your AC outlets. It takes radiation energetic enough to be ionizing to do that (UV wavelengths or shorter like x-rays or gamma rays).

In case you didn't know, shorter wavelengths are more energetic. Visible wavelengths are much shorter than those radio waves radiated by WiFi or ethernet wires, but only a bit longer than those in UV. I assume you don't worry about visible light causing cancer.

And sitting between visible light and radio waves is radiated heat (long infrared). I also assume you aren't worried about heat from objects, even glowing red hot ones like an oven or heating lamp causing cancer.

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  How about distance from the wires?  If you are farther than say, one foot, does that significantly reduce the already low risk?

Comment: Yes. Radiation spreads out in a sphere. So double the distance reduces the power per area by four. Think of a bon fire and the temperature decrease as you double the distance away from it.

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback